# Frequently used symbol "|" in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

The source code is shown above.
Wonder what the symbol "|" stands for?
Will really appreciate your answer and thanks for the reply;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short: that is a [bitwise OR](http://objectivecc.blogspot.com/2012/04/bitwise-operator-or-and-and-in.html) operation.

It is tipically used in generating bitmasks.

With this operation you can combine flags into on binary number.

For example: possible flags for [UIViewAutoresizing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW45) are:

```
enum {
   UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,           // = 0b 0000 0000 =  0
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,      // = 0b 0000 0001 =  1
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,      // = 0b 0000 0010 =  2
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,      // = 0b 0000 0100 =  4
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,      // = 0b 0000 1000 =  8
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,      // = 0b 0001 0000 = 16
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5       // = 0b 0010 0000 = 32
};
typedef NSUInteger UIViewAutoresizing;
```

Statement:

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

is esentially the same as:

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

(since both operands are the same).

If you would ask about:

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

this would set `self.autoresizingMask` to:

```
(1<<1)|(1<<4)=(0b 0000 0010)|(0b 0001 0000)=0b 0001 0010 = 9
```

Bitwise OR is not to be confused by [Logical OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) used with *simple* true/false algebra.

There is some relation between the two (bitwise or can be understood as a logical or between the bits on the same position) but that is about it.

Answer (score 10):

| is the bitwise OR operator in C (and therefore in Objective-C).

See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

In the context you asked about, it's being used to combine two flag values.

Answer (score 4):

The | character denotes an inclusive-or bitwise operation. which operates under the premise with matching the bitstrings of two objects.

if you have a bitstring 1101 and another 1001 the inclusive or of the two would produce 1011. Basically if the current bit is the same in both strings then a 1 is outputted in its place otherwise a 0 is.

Answer (score 2):

That is a bitwise OR operation, maybe this can help you : [Bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)